# Get LR from cyclical learning rate in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to implement the [cyclical learning rate](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186) approach on top of the PyTorch [reimplementation of StyleGAN by rosinality](https://github.com/rosinality/style-based-gan-pytorch). To do so, I am building on what suggested in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/adaptive-and-cyclical-learning-rates-using-pytorch-2bf904d18dee) blog post.

To check how the loss changes as a function of the learning rate, I need to plot how the (LR, loss) changes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/749b02cb184c06198d3b6a46dba4abe5) you can find my modified version of train.py. These are the main changes I made:

1. Define `cyclical_lr`, a function regulating the cyclical learning rate

`def cyclical_lr(stepsize, min_lr, max_lr):`

```
    # Scaler: we can adapt this if we do not want the triangular CLR
    scaler = lambda x: 1.

    # Lambda function to calculate the LR
    lr_lambda = lambda it: min_lr + (max_lr - min_lr) * relative(it, stepsize)

    # Additional function to see where on the cycle we are
    def relative(it, stepsize):
        cycle = math.floor(1 + it / (2 * stepsize))
        x = abs(it / stepsize - 2 * cycle + 1)
        return max(0, (1 - x)) * scaler(cycle)

    return lr_lambda
```

2. Implement the cyclical learning rate for both the discriminator and the generator

   ```
   step_size = 5*256
   end_lr = 10**-1
   factor = 10**5
   clr = cyclical_lr(step_size, min_lr=end_lr / factor, max_lr=end_lr)
   scheduler_g = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(g_optimizer, [clr, clr])

   d_optimizer = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=args.lr, betas=(0.0, 0.99))
   scheduler_d = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(d_optimizer, [clr])
   ```

Do you have suggestions on how to plot how the loss changes as a function of the learning rate? Ideally, I would like to do it using TensorBoard, where for now I am plotting the generator loss, the discriminator loss and the size of the generated images as a function of the iteration number:

```
    if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
        writer.add_scalar('Loss/G', gen_loss_val, i * args.batch.get(resolution))
        writer.add_scalar('Loss/D', disc_loss_val, i * args.batch.get(resolution))
        writer.add_scalar('Step/pixel_size', (4 * 2 ** step), i * args.batch.get(resolution))
        print(args.batch.get(resolution))
```